# Translation of "personal statement"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What phrase in Spanish is used to describe a "personal statement" (i.e. a short essay composed for a college application, for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term I think is most close to `personal statement` is `carta de intención`.

Comment: *carta de presentación* is also commonly used.

Comment: As I have seen, when you are applying for something, "carta de intención" or "carta de recomendación" (recomendation letter) is written by other people in you behalf. But "carta de intención" is written by you as an essay about why you want to be in a course, for example.

Answer (score 3):

*Carta de presentación* is what is commonly used for "Personal Statement" like the one that you write for college entrance.